# Why doesn't form submit when it is in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: c#, html, forms, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

Already figured out the issue, but I assume someone else will encounter something similar.
I tried adding an `Html.BeginForm` to a modal in both the main view and in a partial view.

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel">Select Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Something)
                        <label>Something</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SomethingElse)
                        <label>Something Else</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" value="Save" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it is a basic form setup and all looks good. What I encountered was the `data-dismiss="modal"` tag in my 'submit' button kept the form from submitting.
I just removed that and all worked well. Took way too long to figure out suck a simple issue.

Here's how the button should look:

```
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
```